# How to serve an image layer with tilestache

Tags: openlayers-2, mapnik, imagery, tilestache

I have some .png images with associated .wld and .tfw files.

I'd like to display this in OpenLayers, and I already have a Tilestache server running, so it would be good to leverage this.

OpenLayers supports drawing an image with [ol.layer.Image](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Image.html?unstable=true), but this requires you to provide the geographic boundaries of the image in the Javascript.  What I would like to do is have this done on the server side, through Tilestache if possible.

Does Tilestache provide some way of doing this?